# C# alter stored procedure programmatically

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I have the following C# code that *should* allow me to modify (alter) a stored procedure of mine:

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlConnection"].ConnectionString);
ServerConnection srvCon = new ServerConnection(sqlCon);

sqlCon.Open();

Server srv = new Server(srvCon);
Database db = srv.Databases[sqlCon.Database];
StoredProcedure sp = new StoredProcedure(db, "spRDLDataFetcher");

sp.TextMode = false;
sp.AnsiNullsStatus = false;
sp.QuotedIdentifierStatus = false;
sp.TextBody = "SELECT blah FROM MyTable WHERE ID=1";
sp.Alter();
```

However, the `sp.Alter()`call throws this error:

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException: 'Alter failed for StoredProcedure 'dbo.spRDLDataFetcher'. '
>
> Inner Exception: InvalidSmoOperationException: You cannot perform operation Alter on an object in state Creating.

What am I missing in order to get it to alter (update) that stored procedure?

Comment: You'll save yourself a lot of time and hassle by ditching SMO, and just send a complete "ALTER PROCEDURE" batch using SqlClient.

Comment: Don't you mean `sp = db.StoredProcedures["spRLDataFetcher"]`? I believe the alternative is to call `sp.Refresh()` right after the `new` so SMO realizes it already exists. (Alhough I absolutely agree with @David here -- every time I've used SMO it's ended up being more trouble than it's worth, even for the tasks it should nominally excel at.)

Comment: Can not do what @DavidBrowne-Microsoft suggested due to me just changing a few things within the SP. I'm replacing comments (--something) with data. The **textBody=** above is just an example and not my real SP that I will be altering.

Comment: Even for programmatically replacing the stored procedure body, a `SELECT [definition] FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('myprocedure')` will do. Patch the text, replace the first `CREATE` with `ALTER`, send it back. But SMO does slightly better here in terms of lines of code needed.

Comment: Are you sure the stored procedure `spRDLDataFetcher` already exists?

Comment: @spodger yes I am sure

Comment: OK. It's just that the error suggests either it doesn't or that you are trying to create one. Have you tried `sp.Create()` instead of `sp.Alter()` just to see what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so I found out why it was not updating it. Seems, for whatever reason, it needed **sp.Refresh();** `First` before I overwrote the textBody.

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlConnection"].ConnectionString);
ServerConnection srvCon = new ServerConnection(sqlCon);

sqlCon.Open();

Server srv = new Server(srvCon);
Database db = srv.Databases[sqlCon.Database];
StoredProcedure sp = new StoredProcedure(db, "spRDLDataFetcher");

sp.TextMode = false;
sp.AnsiNullsStatus = false;
sp.QuotedIdentifierStatus = true;
sp.ImplementationType = ImplementationType.TransactSql;
sp.Schema = "dbo";

sp.Refresh(); //What was needed to make work
string orgSPText = sp.TextBody;

sp.TextBody = "SELECT blah FROM MyTable WHERE ID=1";
sp.Recompile = true;
sp.Alter();
```

The **sp.Recompile = true;** really is not needed. It will work without it but I like to keep that in there just for kicks and giggles.

Comment: That's not "for kicks and giggles", it adds [`WITH RECOMPILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/recompile-a-stored-procedure) to the stored procedure. This can be a good, bad or indifferent thing, but it has an impact at runtime, so don't just throw it in because you can. (It has nothing to do with what SMO does to alter the stored procedure; in particular, it does not instruct the database to recompile the procedure at that moment, as that will happen when the new procedure is first executed.)

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge @JeroenMostert

Comment: sp.Refresh() fills the c# object properties from the StoredProcedure. For whatever reason, when I try this, it does not throw an error any longer, but it fails to actually update the sp in the database.. As I have made a change to validate whether it works or not. This is not sqlExpress, this is on a full blown 2014 or 2016 server, using sql logins.